# How can I resolve the speed loss of this display with matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I made a code to display the prime numbers in this way: whenever n is a prime number, the path is changed 90 degrees counterclockwise. You can see an example here: [post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/jcjy9r/oc_prime_numbers_whenever_n_is_a_prime_number_the/)
To do this, I created an array X with two rows (x and y) and in each column there is the position step by step.
For the animation,  I plotted the segment joining two adjacent points in a for loop:

```
plt.plot([X[0][a - 2], X[0][a - 1]], [X[1][a - 2], X[1][a - 1]])
plt.pause(0.1) #This changes several times
```

As you can see in the link I put above, it slows down a lot as the number of steps increases. I verified that it is due to matplotlib, not the position calculation with numpy.
How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

So each time you do a draw, it recalculates the x/y lim for you.  As you have more data that gets slower.  It is particularly slow, because you have sent the individual segments to matplotlib as separate lines.    My guess is that this is your bottle neck.

Since you know the data already, suggest you do:

```py
plt.autoscale(False)
plt.xlim(min(X[0][:a]), max(X[0][:a]))
plt.ylim(min(X[1][:a]), max(X[1][:a]))
```

You can also drastically improve things by only having one line `l` that you update the data for.  Autoscaling may even be fast enough for this case that you can just let matplotlib do it.

```py
# first draw
l,  = plt.plot(X[0][:1], X[1][:1], 'r')

for a in range(len(X[0]):
    l.set_data(X[0][:a], X[1][:a])
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

More examples at https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html